# please help me with Error 27506 Error executing SQL script

Tags: sql-server, installshield, sql-scripts

I'm trying to create a setup file using InstallShield 2010 for my project which uses SQL Server 2008

Everything is ok all necessary programs are being installed but when I try to install my project it will give this error

> *Error 27506. Error executing SQL script dbName.sql Line 9
>
>   Create Database failed. some file names listed could not be created Check
>   related errors (1802)*

I searched it says that my path in SQL script does not exist but how to make database to be created in installation folder of program itself?

Here first few lines of my SQL script

```
USE [master]
GO

/****** Object:  Database [InventoryDB]    Script Date: 08/11/2012 19:01:00 ******/
CREATE DATABASE [InventoryDB] ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'InventoryDB', FILENAME = N'C:\Inventory\DB\InventoryDB.mdf' , SIZE = 2048KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1024KB )
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'InventoryDB_log', FILENAME = N'C:\Inventory\DB\InventoryDB_log.ldf' , SIZE = 2816KB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 10%)
GO

ALTER DATABASE [InventoryDB] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 100
GO
```

please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your setup app should create the path C:\INVENTORY\DB before trying to create the database there.

Comment: I don't know InstallShield, but I think that you should search on its documentation how to create a folder. Insert, in you setup, the action that create the folder and then proceed with the database script.

Comment: Why bother specifying the location at all?  In this example the MDF and LDF are both going on C:.  That doesn't provide any value.  SQL will create the device files based on it's instance configuration if you'll let it.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem. I rename the old .mdf and .ldf files and work.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure InventoryDB.mdf' and InventoryDB_log.ldf' file does not exist already.

Also make sure that sql account have below persmission

securityadmin
 dbcreator
 db_owner database role membership

Answer (score 0):

I resolved mine by checking the installation log files i had available. Mine was that the Log and MDF files already existed in the directory. Deleted these files, and installed successfully.

Regards,
Kiran